# Interstitial Ad onBackPressed from default video player

Tags: android, android-activity, onbackpressed, admob

I am making a TV channel streaming app which when click on a channel from a list view it goes to another activity and a pop up of player selection comes and after selecting a player plays video. Now i am implementing admob interstitial ad which should be displayed directly onBackPressed and then after closing ad goes to my "Activity A" (first activity) and not the second activity B. It works flawelessly but when i press backbutton it goes to second activity blank screen and then on back press to ad.How i can do this to show ad on backpress from default selected video player. here is some code

Activty A

```
case 1:
                    i = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
                    i.putExtra("channel","http://id=HBO");
                    startActivity(i);
                    break;
```

Activity B

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    String channel = bundle.getString("channel");
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(channel);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "video/mp4");
    startActivity(intent);
```

and onBackPressed

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
        interstitial.show();
    }
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the ad is loaded you show it which is fine, but you still call through to `super.onBackPressed()`. This causes the activity to finish and return to the last activity.

What you need to do is add an else clause which will call `super.onBackPressed();` only if the ad is not loaded.

Then you need to add a listener to your interstitial ad that will listen for the ad closed event and call `finish();` there.

Comment: where should i place the listener? Also from default video player it first show the second activity and not the ad directly.i dont want to show second activity at all on backpress.

Comment: The listener can be added after you create the new interstitial ad in your code. e.g.

`mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAdClosed() {
       finish();
    }
});`

See: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/interstitial#create_the_adlistener for more info.

Comment: How can i get rid of second activity. onBackPressed function is on second activity?

Comment: Can you post a simple diagram of the flow of your app? even something simple like Activity A -> B etc?

Comment: Ok here it is. I got my channel list view on MainActivity. i click on channel and it goes to 2nd Acitvity i-e, MainActivity->2nd Activity. In 2nd activity default player pop up and i select on. now the channel is streaming. Now when i press back while playing video it comes to 2nd Activity which i dont want to show. here is flow chart what happens. MainActivity->2nd Activity->user selected player->backButton->2ndActivity->back button->Ad->backbutton->MainActivity. I want this thing user selected player->backbutton->Ad->backbutton->Mainactivity

Comment: Ah, you don't want the user to return to Activity B after leaving the video?

Comment: Exactly! Wanna show direct Ad and then MainActivity

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133432/discussion-between-user7410521-and-user2592807).